# Rails 4 + serialization: Nested models not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I am using the Active Model Serialization Gem to pull info for my API and my nested models are not working properly.

I have the following:

```
class API::ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :name, :address
    has_many :check_ins
end

class API::CheckInSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :employee, :created_at, :type_of_weighin, :user_id

    has_one :weigh_in
end
```

and while the `check_ins` show when I pull a `client`.  The `weigh_in` is never included in the `check_in`.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Can you show us your controller? It could be that the there is no `weigh_in` in your `CheckIn` object.

Comment: I never made a `check_ins` api controller as I didn't need to make anything additional to grab the `check_ins`.  I do have a non-api `CheckInsController` if that would help

Comment: I got it working by adding a custom `weigh_ins` method and adding `:weigh_ins` to my `attributes`.  The `weigh_ins` method simply returns `object.weigh_in`.  While this works, it doesn't really answer why my nesting isnt working